# Constructing object in freestore using "new ClassType(std::move(/*class_object*/))"

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator, move-semantics, move-constructor

Beginner's question:

```
Class Quote {
    public:
    /* ..... */

    virtual Quote* clone() const & {return new Quote(*this);}

    virtual Quote* clone() && {return new Quote(std::move(*this));} // (***)

    /* ..... */
}
```

Objects allocated by ***new*** are in the free-store. ****this*** is whatever object that calls ***clone()*** and is not necessarily a dynamically-allocated object.

How does the move mechanism work if the moved-from and moved-to objects are in different memory areas? Or perhaps they're never really in different areas and I'm missing something?

From what I understand, the move constructor creates new overheads that  link to the data/memory part of the moved-from object. The data itself is not moved/changed. How does this work in the above case? If it works the same way then after ***new*** runs wouldn't we have a dynamically-allocated object that sit outside free-store (wherever ****this*** is located?) Is this somehow resolved by ***std::move()***? I'm not exactly sure how/why ***std::move()*** work besides that it force-returns an rvalue reference to a named object making it possible to move from that object.

Comment: This example won't compile and I think you're trying to invoke c++11 magic where it can't. Move semantics actually "move", so your clone functions if they should clone must copy the object.

Comment: @dornhege I'm actually wondering the same thing. The code is from a book I'm reading (c++ primer 5th ed, chp 15.8). When you put it like that then yes it doesn't really make sense to have a clone function that doesn't clone stuff, but idk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand, the move constructor creates new overheads
>   that link to the data/memory part of the moved-from object.  The data
>   itself is not moved/changed.

Not true.  A *typical* move constructor ((I emphasize *typical* because a move constructor can really do anything the class writer wants it to do) will "steal" resources which another object owns remotely *(e.g. a dynamically allocated array)*, by reassigning handles *(e.g. a pointer to a dynamically allocated array)*

When I say the resource is owned remotely, I mean it is not actually a data member of the class.  The handle, however, *is* a data member of the class.  The handle refers to the resource.  The moved to object and the moved from object have distinct addresses and data members.  Their data is able to be moved efficiently because it is not actually part of the class, it is referred to by the handle.  The handle, unlike the resource, is small, and cheap to copy.  "Moving" is actually copying handles from a source object to a destination object, then nullifying the handles in the source object so that its destructor doesn't destroy the resource.

> How does the move mechanism work if the moved-from and moved-to
>   objects are in different memory areas?

(Again I am speaking of a *typical* move constructor) It's irrelevant.  Wherever they happen to be stored, they still have the same memory layout.  The handles are modified exactly the same.  The resource will be released when the destructor of the moved-to object is called (unless that object too is moved from).  That means either when the object goes out of scope, if it is on the stack, or when `delete` is called on a pointer pointing to it, if it is on the free-store. (There are other possibilities, but those two are obviously the most common)

Comment: For a class which owns no remote resources, the move constructor is typically identical to the copy constructor, or the move constructor is deleted, and the copy constructor is used for r-values.  Does that answer the question you started to ask, but deleted?

Comment: Thank you. That was what I had in mind but couldn't really put to words. I was wondering that, strictly in the case above, if the class doesn't manage dynamic memory then wouldn't there be no point in using the move constructor since the new class would be constructed similarly to when using the copy constructor. That clarifies it. Again thank you for your time and your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A move does not move *everything*. Builtin data types like ints and pointers, for example can't be moved, they just can be copied. Moving is pure semantics. Best example is a `std::vector` or a `std::string`. Both typically contain a pointer to some dynamically allocated memory and some other variables. Said memory *semantically* belongs to the `vector` object, meaning it has to free the memory, it may alter its contents, it has control over it and is the only one to do so. The common term is "the `vector` has *ownership* of the allocated memory".
Now, when you copy a vector, the original will keep that ownership, and the copy will have to allocate it's own memory. In contrast, when you *move* a vector, the move-constructed new vector is allowed to steal the allocated memory, taking over the ownership of the resource the original vector once posessed. This can be done because the original vector is about to go out of scope anyways, and it does not need that resource any more.
However, the actual data members of the moved `vector` are not moved themselves. Since they are pointers and maybe ints, they can only be copied. After that has been done, the pointers and ints in the original get changed in a way that *semantically* ends its ownership of the allocated memory.

In short: moving is a semantic thing, on the lower technical level it is mostly a copy and setting the original to zero.